# remove author name in latex with IEEEtran template

Tags: ieeetran

In sigconf we can set anonymous=True. How can I anonymize author name in an IEEEtran template in conference mode?

Answer (score 3):

Use `\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle` command
(in addition to and after the traditional `\maketitle`),  usually just after the abstract.

Comment: that worked.. thank you!

Comment: This did not work for me, please what is an alternative?
highly stressed.

Comment: It seems the document class should be `\documentclass[peerreview, 10pt]{IEEEtran}`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this after the title: `\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Anonymous Authors}}`. The above solution didn't work for me.